# What is `-plain.war` in grails 5 `build/libs/`?

Tags: grails

I use grails 5 official [start](https://start.grails.org/) to create project:

```sh
curl -O https://start.grails.org/restPproject.zip -d profile=rest-api
unzip restPproject.zip
cd restPproject
chmod +x gradlew grailsw
sed -i 's/org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:2.1.0/org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:2.1.1/' build.gradle
./grailsw war
```

And I find when I use `./grails war` will generate 2 war files in `build/libs/`:

```
$ ls build/libs/
restPproject-0.1-plain.war  restPproject-0.1.war
```

What is `-plain.war` ? And how could I build a standalone runnable war and can be deploy to a servlet container like Jetty at one time build?

I find both `-plain.war` and `.war` cannot run under Jetty 10:

```sh
$ cp build/libs/restPproject-0.1-plain.war webapps/ROOT.war
$ docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 -v `pwd`/webapps:/var/lib/jetty/webapps/ jetty:10-jre11-slim

2021-12-03 10:55:34.467:WARN :oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@6150c3ec{ROOT.war,/,file:///tmp/jetty/jetty-0_0_0_0-8080-ROOT_war-_-any-7013661700671242562/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/var/lib/jetty/webapps/ROOT.war}
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.juli.logging.Log: org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog not a subtype
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.<init>(LogFactory.java:94)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:69)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.<init>(WsWebSocketContainer.java:92)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.<init>(WsServerContainer.java:83)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.init(WsSci.java:137)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:49)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContainerInitializerHolder.doStart(ServletContainerInitializerHolder.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$ServletContainerInitializerStarter.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:1660)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:369)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1304)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:895)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:306)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:532)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:40)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:183)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:516)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:456)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:58)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$DiscreteListener.pathAdded(Scanner.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:836)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:802)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:709)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:158)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:605)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:469)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:414)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.lambda$main$4(XmlConfiguration.java:1867)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1810)
2021-12-03 10:55:34.491:INFO :oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@77a98a6a{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
```

```sh
$ cp build/libs/restPproject-0.1.war webapps/ROOT.war
$ docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 -v `pwd`/webapps:/var/lib/jetty/webapps/ jetty:10-jre11-slim

2021-12-03 10:56:21.615:WARN :oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@6150c3ec{ROOT.war,/,file:///tmp/jetty/jetty-0_0_0_0-8080-ROOT_war-_-any-15153155136947335580/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/var/lib/jetty/webapps/ROOT.war}
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatServletWebServerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory]: Factory method 'tomcatServletWebServerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.juli.logging.Log: org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog not a subtype
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:99)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175)
        at org.grails.boot.context.web.GrailsAppServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(GrailsAppServletInitializer.groovy:57)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContainerInitializerHolder.doStart(ServletContainerInitializerHolder.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$ServletContainerInitializerStarter.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:1660)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:369)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1304)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:895)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:306)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:532)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:40)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:183)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:516)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:456)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:58)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$DiscreteListener.pathAdded(Scanner.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:836)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:802)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:709)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:158)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:605)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:469)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:414)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.lambda$main$4(XmlConfiguration.java:1867)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1810)
Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory]: Factory method 'tomcatServletWebServerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.juli.logging.Log: org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog not a subtype
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:99)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175)
        at org.grails.boot.context.web.GrailsAppServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(GrailsAppServletInitializer.groovy:57)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContainerInitializerHolder.doStart(ServletContainerInitializerHolder.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$ServletContainerInitializerStarter.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:1660)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:369)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1304)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:895)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:306)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:532)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:40)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:183)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:516)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:456)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:58)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$DiscreteListener.pathAdded(Scanner.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:836)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:802)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:709)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:158)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:605)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:469)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:414)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.lambda$main$4(XmlConfiguration.java:1867)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1810)
Caused by: 
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.juli.logging.Log: org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog not a subtype
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.<init>(LogFactory.java:94)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:69)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.<clinit>(AprLifecycleListener.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getDefaultLifecycleListeners(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:172)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.<init>(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:120)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.tomcatServletWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration.java:76)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:99)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175)
        at org.grails.boot.context.web.GrailsAppServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(GrailsAppServletInitializer.groovy:57)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContainerInitializerHolder.doStart(ServletContainerInitializerHolder.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$ServletContainerInitializerStarter.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:1660)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:369)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1304)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:895)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:306)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:532)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:40)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:183)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:516)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:456)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:58)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$DiscreteListener.pathAdded(Scanner.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:836)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:802)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:709)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:158)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:605)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:469)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:414)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.lambda$main$4(XmlConfiguration.java:1867)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1810)
2021-12-03 10:56:21.658:INFO :oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@85b9f9c{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
```

Thanks.

Comment: "And how could I build a standalone runnable war and can be deploy to a servlet container like Jetty at one time build?" - Do you want the war to be both standalone runnable and also deployable to Jetty?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown It would be best if it could be implemented. Otherwise build 2 war files at one time build, one can be standalone runnable and the other can be deployed to Jetty is OK. Thanks.

Comment: "It would be best if it could be implemented." - Does `./gradlew assemble` give you what you want?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown No. This is the same result as `./grails war`, just as my post describe. both `-plain.war` and `.war` cannot run in Jetty.

Comment: I _think_ what you are seeing is either a misconfigured project or a bug in the framework.  It isn't clear why the app is trying to create the tomcatServletWebServerFactory bean but it might be something broken in the framework.  If that is what it looks like, please file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues.  Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Thank you. I've submitted an issue: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/12237.

Comment: I see now that your instructions above lead to you using the tomcat starter, which is probably not what you want since you are deploying to Jetty.

Comment: Thank you. But I try to replace `implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"` with `implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty"`, I got another error: `Unable to find ServletContextHandler for provided ServletContext`. See: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/12237#issuecomment-988771446

Answer (score 3):

In `Grails 5`, there 3 ways to package your app: `(1) grails package`, `(2) ./gradlew assemble` and `(3) grails war`. both of them can make 2 files: `myapp-0.1.war` and `myapp-0.1-plain.war`. ([Grails Docs - 21 Deployment](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/deployment.html))

the `.war` file is completely consistent in the 3 ways, and its a `Runnable WAR`, so you can run it like this: `java -jar build/libs/myapp-0.1.war`.

the `-plain.war` is a little different, it is consistent in the way of (1) and (3), but in the way of (2), a `micronaut-inject-groovy-*.jar` is added in `WEB-INF/lib`, and it is `NOT` a `Runable WAR`, it is used for Servlet container deployment, such as `Tomcat`.

the difference between `.war` and `-plain.war` is that there are used for different purposes. there is a `spring-boot-jarmode-layertools-*.jar` with configuration file `layers.idx` in `.war` for easier `Docker Deployment` than before (manual unpacking is no longer required), for more details see the spring-boot docs.([1.2. Layering Docker Images](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/container-images.html#container-images.efficient-images.layering))

Comment: Thank you very much. But `-plain.war` cannot run under Jetty. What's wrong? How can I build a `-plain.war` that can run under Jetty? Thanks.

Comment: "the .war file is completely consistent in the 3 ways" - What are the 3 ways?

Comment: @FengYu the grails docs said '2.11 Supported Java EE Containers - Jetty 8 or above',  and I see that you are using docker to run the Grails project. You can try to run the `-plain.war`  directly in the jetty environment as first.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown 
In Grails 5, there `3 ways` to package your app: `(1) grails package, (2) ./gradlew assemble and (3) grails war`

Comment: I am familiar with how to build Grails apps.  Is it the case that what you are saying is the all 3 of the techniques you described create the a `.war` file with the same contents?

Comment: @Aaron.Xu Thank you. But I try to use `-plain.war` still cannot run in Jetty.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown  yes, the contents of the war made by `grails package`, `gradlew assemble` or `grails war` are exactly same.